# Write a Java program that separates the even and odd numbers in an integer array

Tags: java

I need to write a java program that seperates he even and odd numbers in an integer array.

This is what I have so far:
This part is perfect:

```
package Homework;
import java.util.*;
public class EvenOdd
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 integers");
    int [] a= new int[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("The "+(i+1)+" integer = ");
        a[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }     

        System.out.println("\nThe resulting array");
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                int temp;
                if(a[i]%2!=0 && a[j]%2==0 && j>i)
                {
                    temp=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[i];
                    a[j]=temp;
                    break;     //There seems to be some problem in this loop
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The "+(i+1)+" integer = "+a[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Do you also want to sort the elements in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%2` which is modulo, you should be able to find if numbers are even or odd as even numbers mod 2 will equal 0 and odd numbers mod 2 will equal 1.

Try this for sorting the array:

```
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if(a[i] %2 != 0){//even
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i--] = a[count--];
            a[count+1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have already used %2 but I need to get the even numbers on top and odd numbers on the bottom

Comment: You have scanned in the variables, now you need to 'sort' or organize them.

Comment: Exactly but i dont know how to do that

Comment: how exactly does it need to be organized? can it be sorted within two arrays or does it have to be the one?

Comment: Just one array. If you run the program this is what you will get:
Please enter 10 integers
The 1 integer = 1
The 2 integer = 2
The 3 integer = 3
The 4 integer = 4
The 5 integer = 5
The 6 integer = 6
The 7 integer = 7
The 8 integer = 7
The 9 integer = 9
The 10 integer = 10

The resulting array
The 1 integer = 1
The 2 integer = 2
The 3 integer = 3
The 4 integer = 4
The 5 integer = 5
The 6 integer = 6
The 7 integer = 7
The 8 integer = 7
The 9 integer = 9
The 10 integer = 10

I need the resulting array to be all even numbers first and all odd numbers after even numbers

Comment: One array but organized how? Odd numbers then even numbers? Does it matter if they are not in numrical order as long as they are split odds and evens? You need to explain very carefully what you are trying to do.

Comment: They can be in any order. But evens have to be first and then odds

Answer (score 1):

Introduce two Integer type ArrayLists list1 and list2. Put even numbers into list1 and odd numbers into list2. Merge both into list1.

```
public class EvenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 integers");
        int[] a = new int[10];
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("The " + (i + 1) + " integer = ");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                list1.add(a[i]);
            } else {
                list2.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
        list1.addAll(list2);
        for (int b : list1) {
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class main11
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the range");
        int no=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[no];
        int i;
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Even nos are");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]%2==0)
            { 
                System.out.println(a[i]);

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The odd nos are");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]%2!=0)
            { 
                System.out.println(a[i]);

            }

        }




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your swapping of elements is not working due to a typo:

```
temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[i];
a[i]=temp;   //Should be a[i] and not a[j]
break;
```

Also you can reduce the number of iterations by making the following changes in your `for` loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
{
     for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
     {
          int temp;
          if(a[i]%2!=0 && a[j]%2==0) //no need of the last condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//To store even and odd element in 2 diifferent array Aand print it//
import java.util.*;
class main11
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the range");
        int no=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[no];
        int i,j=0,k=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        int even[]=new int[no];
        int odd[]=new int[no];
        System.out.println("Even nos are");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]%2==0)
            { 
                even[i]=a[i];//to store element in even array//
                System.out.println(even[i]+" ");

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The odd nos are");
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]%2!=0)
            {  
                odd[i]=a[i];//to store element in odd array//

                System.out.println(odd[i]+" ");

            }

        }




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j=0,k=0,n;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of element you want in your array:");
         n = scn.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Your array element is : ");
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            array[i]= scn.nextInt();
        }

        int even[] = new int[n];
        int odd[] = new int[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (array[i] % 2 != 0){
                odd[j] = array[i];
                j++;
            }
            else{
                even[k] = array[i];
                k++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Odd Array");
        if (j>1)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<j-1;i++){
                System.out.println(odd[i]+",");
            }
            System.out.println(odd[j-1]);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No number");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Even :");
        System.out.println("Odd Array");
        if (k>1)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<k-1;i++){
                System.out.println(even[i]+",");
            }
            System.out.println(even[k-1]);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No number");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.